# Laravel 5 - Allowing Register Only after Auth and for Admins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm trying to set up the Laravel register page so that /register is available only if :

- `USER` → `IS AUTHENTICATED` = `TRUE`

AND

- `USER` → `TYPE` = "`STAFF`" (stored in the database)

Which file needs to be modified so that *staff* users can register new *patient* users? In this case, public registration would be turned off for normal/patients users.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are using the builtin auth, but for the first part, you want to add the auth middleware to your RegisterController's constructor (app/Http/Controllers/Auth)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

That will make it a requirement that the user be authenticated before hitting the registration

For the second part... that largely depends on how you want to control things but the best way i would say is to take a look at https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/13

I followed that to setup mine, pretty straight forward and much cleaner way to handle this imo

Answer (score 0):

To modify the auth files that come with Laravel...

For starters, disable auto-login after registration so that the logged-in staff user doesn't immediately switch over to the newly-registered patient user. Override register() in your RegisterController (`app/Http/Controllers/Auth`) with this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
           ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

You're doing this to leave out one line, `$this->guard()->login($user);`, that is in the original RegisterController register().

Then you'll need to create a new middleware to redirect users if they go to the register view but are not staff. Use `php artisan make:middleware IsStaff` to create a new class in your `app/Http/Middleware` directory:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IsStaff
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        if (auth()->user()->type != 'Staff') {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

You'll need to register the new middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'isStaff' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsStaff::class,
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
];
```

Back in your RegisterController, use both the built-in auth middleware and your new IsStaff middleware:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'isStaff']);
    }
```

Registration should now be inaccessible to guests and users who are not staff! I've implemented something similar in my own project, let me know if something is amiss.